# How to access ScrollViewer in DevExpress GridControl?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, scrollviewer, gridcontrol

I have to access to ScrollViewer in GridControl to do a synchronization with my other GridControls on scrolling.

Before I used vanilla DataGrid and it was quite easy to get ScrollViewer via VisualTreeHelper and then to subscribe to the ScrollChanged events.

I tried the same approach with GridControl but no luck. `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()` gives me 0 and also `LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren()` gives me an empty iterator.

But..

WPF Snooper can access logical and visual trees just perfectly perfect!
So, what I've done wrong and why I am not able to get the information WPF Snooper is able to get?

Comment: I suspect that I am trying to get that value too early in the process when visual tree is not built yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was the case! I tried to initialize it too early.

I did it in constructor, when it was initialized yet.

If someone needs solution how to synchronize data grids (it doesn't matter if this is vanilla **DataGrid** or *DevExpress* **GridControl** or mix of them) to show the same data when you are horizontally scrolling and you have more columns then you can show then here is the solution:

In your constructor:

```
    mainDataGrid.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
                           {
                               ScrollViewer sv = mainDataGrid.FindVisualTreeChild<ScrollViewer>();

                               if (sv != null)
                                   sv.ScrollChanged += DataGridScrollChanged;

                           };
```

Add the event handler for ScrollChanged event:

```
private void DataGridScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HorizontalChange == 0.0f)
        return;
    ScrollViewer sv = dependentDataGrid1.FindVisualTreeChild<ScrollViewer>();
    if (sv != null)
        sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);

    sv = dependentDataGrid2.FindVisualTreeChild<ScrollViewer>();
    if (sv != null)
        sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);
}
```